# Php puts <h5> tag into wrong way

Tags: php, html, html-heading

I have this code, that generates the menu from sql.

```
<footer class="footer-basic-centered">
  <p class="footer-links">
    <?php 
    $top_menuDown = mysqli_query($kapcs, "SELECT * FROM top_menu WHERE latszik = 1 AND (top_menu_place = 1 OR top_menu_place = 0) ORDER BY top_menu_sorrend ASC");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($top_menuDown) > 0 )
    {
        while($top_nav = mysqli_fetch_assoc($top_menuDown))
        {
            echo '<a class="footer_menu_to_link" href="'.$host.'/'.$top_nav['top_menu_seo'].'" title="'.$top_nav['top_menu_nev'].'"><h5 class="kat_h5">'.$top_nav['top_menu_nev'].'</h5></a>'."\n";
        }
    }
    ?>
  </p>
  <h6 class="copy"><p class="footer-company-name"><?php echo date("Y"); ?> <?php echo $siteName; ?> &copy;  - Minden jog fentartva!</p></h6>
</footer>
```

As you can see it on the image i uploaded, at the first link, the `<h5>` tag is outside the `<a>`. The other links are okay.

Whats going on there?

[image]

Comment: You're not really looking at the HTML source code. You're seeing how the browser has interpreted the code. Have a look at the real source code.

Comment: @Parkolo11 that's "live" source in developper toolbar, it may be different from the generate one. Have a look at the real Html source (Crl+U). that will show your real HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting a `h5` in an `a` that is in a `p`. That is not going to do what you think.

The `p` will get closed automatically when you add a new block-level element like a `h5`.

Comment: I replace the p with a div.  Thanks!